# Divide Db Query Result into as many tasks as I want

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, task, semaphore

I want to divide the Db Query Result into as many tasks as I want. How can I do? For example, I want to give every 300 rows to the same process at the same time, but every 300 rows must be different 300 rows.

Comment: It seems like want to perform multiple query fetches and process them in different tasks? That sounds like pagination combined with task

Comment: What's the actual problem/ You described how you think the problem is solved, not what the actual problem is. Executing 100 paging queries is a LOT slower than executing 1 query and partitioning the data on the client. Each paging query has to skip the previous pages, so each one will take longer than the previous one

Comment: The actual problem is , normally I have a huge select query. And this query rows will go to as parameter to a function. I want split to same counts this query rows and work as same time for earn from time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean

> I want to give every 300 rows to the same process at the same time

However, one possible solution for dividing the query result into a list of tasks could be this:

- Count total records:

  ```
  var count = await context.Entities.CountAsync();
  ```
- Calculate the total database call you need:

  ```
  const int take = 300;
  var dbCallsCount = Math.Ceiling((double)count / take);
  ```
- Create a method to fetch data (note that you cannot run parallel queries through the same `DbContext` object):

  ```
  public async Task<List<Entity>> FetchDataAsync(int page, int take)
  {
       using(var context = new DbContext("ConnectionString"))
       {
           var result = await context.Entities
                                      .AsNoTracking()
                                      .Skip((page - 1) * take) 
                                      .Take(take)
                                      .ToListAsync();
           return result;
       }
  }
  ```
- Create a List of tasks to fetch data:

  ```
  var taskList = new List<Task<List<Entity>>>();

  for(var i = 0; i < dbCallsCount; i++)
      taskList.Add(FetchDataAsync(i, take));

  var result = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
  ```

It can be a generic method to get a list of tasks for fetching data:

```
public async Task<List<Task<List<TEntity>>>> DivideDbQueryIntoTasks<TEntity>(int take) where TEntity : class 
{
    int count;
    using(var context = new DbContext("ConnectionString"))
    {
        count = await context.DbSet<TEntity>.CountAsync();
    }

    var dbCallsCount = Math.Ceiling((double)count / take);
   
    // Local function
    async Task<List<TEntity>> FetchDataAsync<TEntity>(int page, int take)
    {
        using(var context = new DbContext("ConnectionString"))
        {
            var result = await context.DbSet<TEntity>
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Skip((page - 1) * take) 
                .Take(take)
                .ToListAsync();
            
            return result;
        }
    }

    var taskList = new List<Task<List<TEntity>>>();
    for(var i = 0; i < dbCallsCount; i++)
        taskList.Add(FetchDataAsync<TEntity>(i, take));

    return taskList;
}
```

And call it in this way:

```
var tasks = await DivideDbQueryIntoTasks<MyEntity>(300);
foreach (Task<List<IdentityUser>> task in tasks)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohse, this is actually what i want.